# Keyring Warning when running pip list -o

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, python-keyring

I've been trying to run `pip list -o` and `pip list --outdated` to see if any packages need to be updated but it enters a loop of printing: `WARNING: Keyring is skipped due to an exception: Failed to create the collection: Prompt dismissed..`

I've upgraded keyring and the version was already up-to-date. I've seen this keyring warning whilst using `pip install {package} --upgrade` to upgrade other packages as well.

Comment: I have something similar, as far as I understood it's because I setup my OS (Ubuntu) to login without having to enter the password. Not entirely sure about the implications, side-effects, etc. but `keyring --disable` helped in my case. As far as I can see it added en empty `backend` in the `~/.local/share/python_keyring/keyringrc.cfg` file. Some references: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6773 -- https://github.com/jaraco/keyring#disabling-keyring

Comment: Can you specify the OS you're using please, and wither if you're running the pip command from a virtual environment environment or not.

Comment: Please provide more context to this question.

Comment: What is your pip version?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I searched the web about that topic and find that [GitHub issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8090).

If your pip version is any version before "21.1", you can try to upgrade pip to the latest version with `pip install --upgrade pip` command.

Also, as a workaround, you can consider the following answer of `jrd` from the above link:

> Exporting `PYTHON_KEYRING_BACKEND=keyring.backends.null.Keyring` prevent python from using any keyring. `PYTHON_KEYRING_BACKEND=keyring.backends.null.Keyring pipenv update` does not ask me anything anymore.
> So, as a temporary solution, one might want to put this in a .env file.

Comment: This also worked for me directly using pip PYTHON_KEYRING_BACKEND=keyring.backends.null.Keyring  python3 -m pip install